# Saving button count value on jquery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get this script working

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <input type="text" value="valueofButton" id="number"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" id="number1" min="0"/>
  <input type="button" id="increment" value="Increase"/>
  <input type="button" id="decrement" value="Decrease"/>
</body>
</div>

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#increment").click(function(){
      if($('#number1').val() !="0"){
        var $n = $("#number1");
        $n.val(Number($n.val())-1);
        var value = $n.val();
        $("#number").val(value +' valuedisplayed');
       }
    }); 

    $("#decrement").click(function(){
      if($('#number1').val() !="20"){
        var $n = $("#number1");
        $n.val(Number($n.val())+1);
        var value = $n.val();
        $("#number").val(value +' valuedisplayed');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's working well. But I want that the value that user#1 clicks should be displayed when user#2 enter to the page.

For example if user#1 clicked one time at increase button the value will be displayed as 1 click

If user#2 enter to the page and when clicks on increase button the value will be 2 and not 1 (because user#1 has also clicked) or if user#2 clicks decrease the value displayed will be 0

Can I save the information (number of clicked increase/decrease) in a txt file in my server?

How can I do that?

How to make the buttons clickable only once per session?

Comment: While not related, it's funny that when I click `Increment` it decrease the value...

Comment: not possible without any DB interaction

Comment: `Can I save the information in a txt file in my server?` - Yes. It's easy. What have you found so far?. Also `How to make the buttons clickable only once per session?` What do you define as `one session`? Is it one day? One person? One computer? One browser? One user account?

Comment: Need for a server+db/ cloud interaction. If by any means you are going for logging purpose of it, then already there are many ready solutions.. please check google analytics.

Comment: Once per session means one time when the page is visited. If you refresh it you can click again

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very much clear. But if you just to save the value 'number' in txt file, you can make a ajax call to php file where you can save the data as:

```
file_put_contents('sample.txt',$number);
```

Comment: <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#increment").click(function(){
   if($('#number1').val() !="0"){
   var $n = $("#number1");
    $n.val(Number($n.val())-1);
   var value = $n.val();
    $("#number").val(value +' valuedisplayed');
    file_put_contents('sample.txt',$number);
}
});
  $("#decrement").click(function(){
  if($('#number1').val() !="20"){
  var $n = $("#number1");
  $n.val(Number($n.val())+1);
  var value = $n.val();
  $("#number").val(value +' valuedisplayed');
  file_put_contents('sample2.txt',$number);
 }
});
});
</script>

Comment: file_put_contents is a php function not a javascript. You should first make a ajax call to some php page where you can save number using file_put_contents function.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to php. How can I do that?